# change value from of a specific item on button click

Tags: json, react-native

As I asked yesterday in my first post, I have a json file that looks like this:

```
groups:{[
  {
    title:Animal
    shown:false
    data:[{....}]
  }
  ........
 .....
]}
```

I want to change the `shown` value on a button click. The closest thing I found to my problem was this part of code:

```
  newState = this.state.groups.map((val,i) => {
        if(index === i){
            return { ...val, shown: false};
        }
        return val;
    })
    this.setState({
        groups: newState,
    })
```

However, it doesn't seem to work, logging on console doesn't show any differences before and after the button press. I'm rather new to this so do you mind to help me understand what i did bad?

edit: I tried changing from `index` to a simple number to see if that was the problem, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSON object is collection of Key Value pairs. i.e.

```
let FullName = {
  firstName: "Stack",
  lastName: "OverFlow"
}
```

In FullName Object Keys are firstName and lastName and corresponding values are "Stack" and "Overflow".

**The groups Object that you have defined is missing the key Property.**

Coming to Your problem:

Case1: If groups Object is an Array of Objects then:

```js
var groups = [
    {
        title: 'Animal',
        shown: false,
        data: [{}]
    },
    {
        title: 'Birds',
        shown: false,
        data: [{}]
    }

]

/* Upadate By Index value */
/* 
  var index =  1;

  let updatedGroup = groups.map((val,i) => {
    if(index === i){
        return { ...val, shown: true};
    }
    return val;
  })
*/


/* Upadate By title */

/* let title = "Animal";

let updatedGroup = groups.map((val,i) => {
    if(val.title === title){
        return { ...val, shown: true};
    }
    return val;
}) */

// To toggle the shown Value Each Time

let title = "Animal";

let updatedGroup = groups.map((val,i) => {
    if(val.title === title){
        return { ...val, shown: !val.shown};
    }
    return val;
})
console.log("updatedGroup", updatedGroup);
```

Case2: If groups Object is Object of Objects then

```js
var groups = {
    group1: {
        title: 'Animal',
        shown: false,
        data: [{}]
    },
    group2: {
        title: 'Birds',
        shown: false,
        data: [{}]
    }
}

let index = 1;
let updatedGroup = Object.values(groups).map((val, i)=>{
    if(index === i){
        return { ...val, shown: true};
    }
    return val;
}) 

console.log("updatedGroup",updatedGroup)
```

Comment: My groups Object is an Array of Objects, as in the first example. (double checked just now in an editor). I'm using the method that you are showing there. Having checked now, using the `var index = 1` seems to work just fine, could you maybe help me check why the index is not transfered correctly? or if you could show me how to search an item by its title would be much better! Thanks in advance

Comment: I have Updated the Answer. Please, check the case 1. If u have any doubt feel free to ask.

Comment: Meanwhile, I made it work adding an "id" key for each Object present in the Array and using it instead of the index. One more thing i'll have to ask you: how can i tell if its true to set it to false and vice-versa?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get .

Comment: like the `shown` value to switch from false to true and from true to false depending on its previous state. In the example above it just switches to false and that's it, you cant go back to true

Comment: Nevermind, made that work too. Thanks very much for your help kind sir!

Comment: yup, that's exactly what i did too